# Passing command line arguments in C in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have this simple C program to learn how to pass command line arguments, it just doesn't work in my vscode. Tried it in an online compiler and it works, so is there any vscode configurations I should check?

The code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   printf("%i\n hello %s\n", argc, argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: you start the c-program with a launch config, and you can type the arguments in that launch config

Comment: You should check that `argc` is at least two before trying to print `argv[1]`.  The program name is in `argv[0]` if `argc` is not zero.

Comment: how are you running? in terminal? launch config?